# Isometry preserves dot product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, inner-products, isometry

In J.Rotman's "A First Course in Abstract Algebra", page 135.

> **Definition.** An **isometry** of the plane is a function $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ that is distance preserving:
> for all points $P=(a,b)$ and $Q=(c,d)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$,
> $$\parallel\varphi(P)-\varphi(Q)\parallel=\parallel{P-Q}\parallel,$$
> where $\parallel{P-Q}\parallel=\sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}$ is the distance
> from P to Q.
>
> Let $P\cdot Q=ac+bd.$
>
> ....
>
> It follows that every isometry $\varphi$ preserves dot products:
> $$\varphi(P)\cdot\varphi(Q)=P\cdot Q,$$ because
> $$\varphi(P)\cdot\varphi(Q)=\parallel\varphi(P)-\varphi(Q)\parallel^2=\parallel{P-Q}\parallel^2=P\cdot Q.$$

but this seems not right, because
$$2P \cdot Q = \parallel P\parallel^2+\parallel Q\parallel^2 - \parallel P-Q\parallel^2$$
and
$$2\varphi(P) \cdot \varphi(Q) = \parallel \varphi(P)\parallel^2+\parallel \varphi(Q)\parallel^2 - \parallel \varphi(P)-\varphi(Q)\parallel^2,$$
the last terms are equal from isometry, but if I want $\varphi(P)\cdot\varphi(Q)=P\cdot Q$, it seems $\parallel \varphi(P)\parallel^2=\parallel P\parallel^2$ should hold for any point $P$, which may needs $\varphi(O)=O$.

But then **Isom**$(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is defined as all isometries of the plane, its subset consisting of all those isometries with $\varphi(O)=O$ is called ***orthogonal group of the plane*** denoted by $O_2(\mathbb{R})$.

So it seems there should be some isometrics preseving dot product but $O$ not fixed.

Am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you're right.  The isometries that preserve dot products are pure rotations.  Translations also are isometries, but they won't preserve dot products.  It's easy to see that by considering $\varphi((0, 0)) \cdot \varphi((0, 0))$, which only will be $0=(0, 0) \cdot (0, 0)$ if $\varphi((0, 0))=(0, 0)$.

Comment: Nice to see other people watching Eureka seven// But for the question, isometry is just like a rotation / translation/  reflection etc. So, it's geometrically clear that length should be preserved

Comment: Which last terms do you mean? The one in first eqtn and second eqtn in white text?

Comment: @Ethakka Eureka seven is great! Yeah, I mean ||P-Q||^2=||\varphi(P)-\varphi(Q)||^2 from the definition of isometry

Comment: I'm extraordinarily confused. It begins by saying the dot product is defined the normal way, then later evlautes $\phi(P) \cdot \phi(Q_ = || \phi(P) - \phi(Q)||^2$ but that is actually the length of difference vector between map of P and Q but the dot product (conventional sense) is related to projection of one vector to another. Are you sure you're using the same definition of dot prod that the book is using?

Comment: I think, the book simply forgot to add the assumption that $\phi(0)=0$. With this assumption, the claim holds.

Comment: @Ethakka That's just what made me confused, I can't find any way to get this strange equation but not sure if it is wrong.

Comment: @Moishe Looks like it is. So not all isometries preserve dot product.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just find this error has been fixed in later version, it is indeed those isometry fixing $O$, and the strange equation is also corrected.